# Совместная разработка с Git

Tags: bitbucket, git

Сегодня начал вникать в Git. С локальными репозиториями разобрался. Выгрузил проект на удаленный репозиторий bitbucket. Когда делаю push, Git запрашивает пароль. Как избавиться от постоянного ввода пароля? В remote я указал https ссылку, думаю с этим и связана проблема с паролем, но более подробной информации не нашел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать ssh протокол и ключи.

Нужно создать себе ssh ключ (пару: открытый и приватный), и скопировать ваш открытый ключ в настройки доступа к вашему аккаунту на BitBucket:

`https://bitbucket.org/account/user/Ваш_Username/ssh-keys/`

См. их [документацию](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git) (на англ.)

P.s. Могу подробнее объяснить, как это сделать на маке.

Comment: Я сгенерировал ключи. В мануале сказано перед добавлением ключа на bitbucket сделать конфиг файл и обновить .bashrc profile file (вообще не понял что это). Не могли бы пояснить подробнее?

Comment: @Kim

> обновить .bashrc profile file

Этот пункт нужен для gitbash, я таким не занимался, но у меня все работает. Сам файл валяется в домашней папке (~/.bashrc) и выполняется при каждом заходе в систему (таким образом настраивается окружение под пользователя)

> сделать конфиг файл 

Создать или отредактировать `~/.ssh/config`, чтобы принудительно задать ключ для bitbucket.org, там в примере наглядно показано, как это сделать. Этот файл управляет конфигурацией подключений, в данный момент он нужен просто чтобы указать системе, какой ключ брать для bitbucket.org.

Comment: Большое спасибо, разобрался. Последний вопрос, если позволите. Теперь, когда у меня все настроено и есть удаленный репозиторий, что я должен предоставить человеку, совместно с которым я хочу разрабатывать?

Comment: @Kim

> Последний вопрос, если позволите.

Мы здесь сидим, чтобы отвечать на вопросы :)

> Теперь, когда у меня все настроено и есть удаленный репозиторий, что я должен предоставить человеку

Надо зайти в настройки конкретного репозитория и на вкладке Access Management (не знаю как по-русски) добавить нужных пользователей с привилегией write или admin, насколько понимаю.

Comment: Надо, чтобы он завёл себе свой аккаунт на BitBucket, тоже сгенерировал ключи и прописал публичный у себя в настройках. А вы добавьте его аккаунт в настройках общего репо по ссылке примерно `https://bitbucket.org/Ваш_аккаунт/Название_Репо/admin/access`